# Data communication between local apps 2 in c# one in python where speed is the priority

Tags: python, c#, memory-mapped-files

To keep things simple assume I am trying to build essentially three apps one in python the other two in C#.

C# App A will be collecting data from API's processing it and distributing it to a python App and C# App B.

The operating system is Win10 for clarity.

The data will not be huge, probably in the ranges of 1-20kb for most of the time, but updated every 25ms or so in the form of complex Json arrays.

The problem I have is speed. 1ms is a long time to transfer data between the apps as far as this project is concerned.

I have tried named pipes and this seems at first glance to be slower than I thought it would be sending a single message seems to take about 9ms though this could be due to me not implementing it properly. (Using NamedPipeServerStream with one-way direction)

I then tried non-persistent memory map files which seems to do the job where it returns the data in about 1ms.
The only issue is I need to somehow tell the other apps when there is data to be read and possibly how long the data is to read, I have not done enough research on this latter problem yet.

Am I missing a trick here should pipes be faster than this?
Is memory mapping the way to go? if so is there a way to notify of a change in data without checking every 1ms and comparing if the data is the same?
Or am I missing a better way of doing this that I have not found?
(since I am new to coding probably the latter)

I don't want to be spending ages trying new things, and going around in circles to only find out later there is a much better way after all.

Comment: 1. Why are you comparing data, just store a timestamp of last read vs last update.  2. There's no reason to poll data when you can use websockets to push changes.  3.  It sounds like you just need a simple message bus.  This can be done with reddis or rabbitMQ or kafka.

Comment: This is why I asked. I have not heard of these and will look in to them now. Thank you

Comment: :) No problem good luck let me know if you have any other issues.

Comment: Quick question using Redis, is it better to send data via pub/sub or send data to db and notify of change?

Comment: Depends on CAP, do you want to be highly available or consistent?  Personally I like redis because its a multiDB, which means it does pub/sub, acts as a db, or can be a graph db its verify versatile.     I think pub/sub should be fine, I believe redis message bus assures all messages are delivered.